# How to find specific text from a file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

There is one directory which contains many files like a.txt, b.txt,c.txt and so on.

Each file contains a paragraph.

I want to find a specific word "Apple"

Is there any command which tells "Apple" word is present in which files?

Comment: Glad you have some answers, but as mentioned, StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su] or [unix.se] or an internet search , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good lu

Comment: @VikasSharmer : You would need to be more precise what you mean by "the **word** Apple". Do you want to skip _APPLE_ for instance? And what is with _Applet_? Does it count as a match?

Comment: @user1934428 I only want to search apple; not APPLE  or applet.

Comment: @shelter I didn't found any answers on google that's why I asked here.

Comment: @VikasSharma: In your comment, you say that you are searching for _apple_, but in your question, you search for _Apple_. So, what is correct? And: Would _apple-pie_ be a match?

Comment: @VikasSharma : shelter die not propose to use google, and your question would really be better hosted in one of the forums s/he mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an SO question, but for the sake of it, use [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).

If you're in the directory where the files you want to search are, your example would be:

```
grep "Apple" *.txt
```

But grep is much more useful than that: it can search directories recursively, only look in certain files, etc.

UPDATE:

Ok, so I deliberately didn't go into detail but linked the man page for grep, because it isn't an SO question and the best way to learn grep is to try it yourself, which is also why I said it is much more useful than the snippet of code I gave. But following from the comments, if you want to search for the word **Apple** on it's own, not as part of a word like "pineapple", and with that specific capitalisation - i.e. excluding "apple"; then the man page quickly tells you how to do that:

```
grep -w "Apple" *.txt
```

For any of the countless ways in which you can use grep, please read the man page.

Comment: *"which tells "Apple" word is present"* That would be `grep -l srchTarg Files*`. Good luck to all.

Comment: @secretsquirrel : Your proposal would miss _apple_ but report _Applepie_ , which is not the **word** Apple, but a word containing _Apple_ as a substring.

Comment: @secretsquirrel There are paragraphs which may contain apple or APPLE or Applepie or Pineapple, but I want specifically word Apple to be searched.

Answer (score 0):

The command is `grep`

```
grep -ril 'Apple' *
```